# How to use C# 4.0 tasks feature with these properties - assigning variables on run time - keep certain number of tasks alive

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task, multitasking

Alright i have been searching for days but there is no example of what i am trying to achieve. Currently i am able to use tasks for multi-threaded crawling but it is very bad written. You can see the whole code from here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6fa6fd12-85c5-4489-81b1-25bc0126d406

Now coming my question. I want to use System.Threading.Tasks.Task for multi-threading. Development is microsoft visual studio 2010 and C# 4.0.

What i need is

**1-)** I want to keep certain number of tasks running for all the time. So when a thread finished its job another thread should start working immediately. With this way always certain number of threads will be actively running.

**2-)** I need to be able to give tasks variables on run time. So think as i have a links pool. I started with first 100 but lets say 45 th task finished first. So another task will be created and this task will take number 101 th link. When another one finished it will continue as this way and always certain number of tasks will be alive.

**3-)** I need to be able to collect results of tasks. After a task finished somehow collect the result. This part seems like the easiest part.

Whichever task example i found just shows 2 task or 3 task , getting certain variables not changing on run time and not keeping certain numbers alive. Multi-threaded applications are the future but there is so bad documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the [TPL-DataFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14782) CPL yet:

> TPL Dataflow (TDF) is a new .NET library for building concurrent
>   applications. It promotes actor/agent-oriented designs through
>   primitives for in-process message passing, dataflow, and pipelining.
>   TDF builds upon the APIs and scheduling infrastructure provided by the
>   Task Parallel Library (TPL) in .NET 4, and integrates with the
>   language support for asynchrony provided by C#, Visual Basic, and F#.

It's *beta* but I think your problem are not the threads. 
Seems you are trying to build some kind of Agent-based programming model and this DataFlow gives you some really nice tools for this.

Here is the [Homepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582) and here is a nice [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Stephen-Toub-Inside-TPL-Dataflow) on this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I really need examples to understand. Right now downloading video. Actually i am trying to make a crawler. I am going to make a system like google shopping. It will be for Turkey. So will need to crawl lots of product selling websites and i really need to code my crawler and have full control over it.

Comment: No problem - examples are right insdie the Introduction I posted with the first link - but I can insert the first one there

Comment: Ye just noticed that docx file will check that too. Actually what i need is simple. A task handler which will create new tasks when a task finished its job. So when a task finished its job it will callback to task handler and task handler will create another task. The important thing here is variables will be assigned on run time. Also task handler will keep certain number of threads alive.

Comment: And this is more or less what you would call Agent-based system. Only that you don't really care about the threads. What you describe is a inputbuffer and a single consumer that reads the input and works on it. If you want several of these just run several consumers. The TDF was written with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you NEED a certain number of tasks? Let the pool/API decide.

Passing data to tasks is just like passing data to threads: share a data structure.

Use Task to return a result from a task

**EDIT**

> You cannot set the number of worker threads or the number of I/O
>   completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors
>   in the computer.
>
> If the common language runtime is hosted, for example by Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) or SQL Server, the host can limit or
>   prevent changes to the thread pool size.
>
> Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread
>   pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse
>   effect on code libraries you use.
>
> Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems.
>   If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching
>   overhead becomes a significant factor.

([from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx))

Really, you can never force a specific number of tasks to be active. Just create the tasks and allow the run-time to decide which ones should/can run.

If you don't like that, do not use the TPL and bring your own threads.

Comment: sorry but i have to keep certain number of tasks alive it is a must. Probably i will set 250 bounty for this question since it is really really important. I am going to write a full spec crawler for my master degree thesis so on runtime i have to be able to pass variables to the threads.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Then explain why so we can help better. The number of active tasks is dependent on the number of threads in the thread pool. The number of threads is dependent on the hardware and available memory and thus differs from machine to machine. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx

Comment: You are thinking as core number related right ? Well i am going to do not core power consuming tasks like fetching a website. So i need to be able to certain number of tasks alive all the time. Fetching a website is totally depended on your network quality. And if you have ever used some quality tool they all let you decide active threads numbers.

Comment: No you don't. Yes you might specify the number of threads but you can not force them to be active. See my edit in my answer.

Comment: Erno please check this thread. I posted whole source code of my current crawler. Even that crappy code is able to maintain given number of threads alive :) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6fa6fd12-85c5-4489-81b1-25bc0126d406  I think you are misunderstanding what i mean. When a thread finished its job another thread will start working. So total number of active threads will be always certain number.